# binary string to int

Tags: java

I have to convert binary string to integer. I can use & | << and >>. No exponentiation, no embedded functions.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If not, why are you restricted to this method? Can you post an example of the input and expected output?

Comment: This is not a forum for solving homework for you. If you try something and it doesn't work, then post your code and we'll be glad to help you.

Comment: Yes, it's homework. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Do you know how the operators work? What they do? If not: find that out and you will probably find the solution by yourself. If not: improve your question...

Comment: Yes, i known. I known how to convert int to bin string, but how to make binary operators on string?

Comment: I feel tempted to post my comment-less C solution for this. The algorithm is the same, anyway. Any takers with a more obscure language? Something in assembly perhaps :-)

Answer (score 2):

Initialize a value to 0

Traverse the string from left to right as follows:
  Shift the value one bit to the left - <<1
  If the character is '1' add one - |0x1

Comment: @pst: Left to right is fine as long as you shift the result value to the left each time.

Answer (score 1):

try the following. As string is built in, its not possible to use it without using built in methods. ;)

```
String text =
long l = 0;
for(byte b: text.getBytes()) l = (l << 1) | (b & 1);
```

Comment: Nice... taking advantage of the fact that '0' = 0x30 and '1' = 0x31 in ASCII. I'd prefer an explicit condition, but +1 anyway.

Comment: @thkala, I would prefer proper input validation, but then again I would use the builtin methods do this. ;)

Comment: This code depends on the default encoding on the JVM and will fail for example on UTF-16 default encoding systems.

Comment: @Michael, Can you give an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: I think he's trying to say you should use getBytes("UTF-8") since getBytes() will use the default encoding, which might use a different encoding for '0' and '1'.  EBCDIC, for example.

Comment: As long as the encoding for `0` is even and `1` is odd (as it is in EBCDIC) it doesn't matter. The only problem is if `0` and `1` turn into two characters. (I don't know of any which does)

Comment: On a JVM with "UTF-16" as default encoding `"1".getBytes()` will return `[-2, -1, 0, 49]` instead of `[49]` as for "UTF-8" or "ASCII"

Answer (score 0):

Since we are still at it, here's my C-based solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        long long unsigned int r = 0;

        int i;

        if (argc < 2)
            return 1;

        for (i = 0; argv[1][i] != 0; ++i)
                r = (r << 1) | ((argv[1][i] == '1')?1:0);

        printf("%llu\n", r);

        return 0;
}
```

Since it's homework, I intentionally leave the Java translation to the reader. It shouldn't be *too* hard, especially with the answer by Peter Lawrey in mind.